# Switch status in Mysql table with PHP - the easiest way

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysqli table called status with the columns ID, STATUS.

The STATUS can be 1 or 2 only.

I want to update the STATUS column the easiest way, so if the STATUS value is 1, update it to 2 and vice versa.

Normally I can do it like:

```
 $c=$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM status WHERE id="1"' );
    $kats=$c->fetch_assoc();
    $status=$kats['status'];

if ($status == '1') {$newstatus = '2';} else {$newstatus = '1';}

$mysqli->query("UPDATE status SET status = '$newstatus' WHERE id=1" );
```

This will work, but is there an easier way, or maybe 1 row query for this? As the values are just changing from 1 to 2 or from 2 to 1 in one column.

Comment: If the code works and you just want someone to review it, it fits better over at [Core Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). And skip the phrase "the easiest way" since what's "easiest" is usually subjective, since people tend to prioritize differently.

Comment: yeah, I meant the easiest way not to use 5 rows of code, but maybe 1-2 instead. No need to review my code above

Comment: Easiest way is to make an function and just call the function by passing the params to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two values then consider using a Boolean data type. If you do then you can do it in one query, something like this:

```
UPDATE status SET STATUS = !STATUS WHERE ID = ?
```

Also, it's kinda confusing having `status` as both a table and column name.

Comment: How it's even supposed to return 2?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It doesn't but if you really wanted 1's and 2's you could add one to the boolean value returned.